# adjust list (<li>) item by screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, layout

I have a list of times

```
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

which are appearing perfectly on 1900+ screen size. but on small screen size, they are falling in tow or three-line
How can I create something like this which automatically show hide tabs and put extra tabs in more button
[image]

Comment: could you please post some logic you already tried and this menu css ? you have to check the available space on load/resize and change css relatively

Comment: @bluebird, I think he wants to add the list item to the 'More button'. This can't be done with css only.

Comment: @bluebird i was just searching on the net and found this 

https://codepen.io/osvaldas/pen/xWNLXy

this looks like a solution

Comment: Probably you can see this if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/2r03x17h/5/

Comment: @sourabhdevpura yes, that's a good solution, a bit overkill though

Comment: @bluebird how can i make it simple?

Comment: It's not that simple. I suggest you use the useRef hook, assign it to that menu, check that ref on load/resize in a function inside a useEffect hook and modify the menu width relatively to what space is available. And of course that will give you data you need to display or not the "more" button. TLDR : useRef should give you what you need to make your booleans.